# Unable to install neuVector controller on rancher environment

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I install neuvector plugin using rancher now the problem is the controller pod is not deployed successfully it show error

"
Pods "neuvector-controller-pod-9855df76c-" is forbidden: PodSecurityPolicy: unable to admit pod: [spec.volumes[0]: Invalid value: "hostPath": hostPath volumes are not allowed to be used spec.volumes[1]: Invalid value: "hostPath": hostPath volumes are not allowed to be used spec.volumes[2]: Invalid value: "hostPath": hostPath volumes are not allowed to be used spec.volumes[3]: Invalid value: "hostPath": hostPath volumes are not allowed to be used spec.containers[0].securityContext.privileged: Invalid value: true: Privileged containers are not allowed]; Deployment does not have minimum availability.
"

Comment: What is the neuvector version you are trying to install?

Comment: Hi 

https://neuvector.com/

Comment: Hi 

The version is 1,6

Comment: Refer this [document](https://docs.ranchermanager.rancher.io/integrations-in-rancher/neuvector)   to install an  updated version of neuVector controller on rancher environment